# TYPO3 - String before doctype begin

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have a litte problem. I extended the page settings with one field (ext_tables). In this field can the edtor write one or more regional language id's, for example DE, AT or so one.

I need this for a special JSP Tag and it is very important, that this places for the doctype.

This is my first try:

```
config.doctype = <myjsp_lids:setpermissions lids="{TSFE:page|tx_myjsplids}" /><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...
```

But this isn't functional. The reason is easy to find: The doctype is from the datatyp STRING and here can't i place a part from the TSFE.

Maybe know anybody here a good solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the »doctype« property is of data type »string«, and therefore not able to get some data (see http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html?#doctype).

What you need to do is to disable the doctype generation (since you cant use it with dynamic data, but still want to prepend something), prepend the opening HTML-tag instead and get the field data from your your page.

```
config.doctype = none
config.htmlTag_stdWrap.prepend = TEXT
config.htmlTag_stdWrap.prepend.field = tx_myjsplids
config.htmlTag_stdWrap.prepend.wrap = <myjsp_lids:setpermissions lids="|" /><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a partly solution using TypoScript:

You can switch of the doctype and the XML prologue by setting `config.doctype = none` und `config.xmlprologue = none`, and then use `config.htmlTag_stdWrap` ([documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-htmltag-stdwrap)) to generate them again.

Another way would be to write an extension that hooks into the PageRenderer and modifies the output.